# SQL filter records using two columns

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table like this in Teradata. A client can have a record in system 'a' or 'b' or in both. And there is a value which can be null.

| client | system | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 1 |
| B | b | null |
| C | a | 2 |
| C | b | null |
| D | a | null |
| D | b | 3 |
| E | a | 4 |
| E | b | 5 |
| F | a | null |
| F | b | null |

I need to filter the rows so that each client has exactly one row according to the following logic:

- In case there is just one record/one system (client A, B), display it (no matter whether value is NULL or not or what the system is).
- In case a client is in both systems (client C, D) and one value is null, display the row with value NOT NULL.
- In case a client is in both systems and value is NOT null in both (client E) or IS null in both (client F), display system a and not system b.

Put it simply - first prefer value not null and second system a or over system b.

Result:

| client | system | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | 1 |
| B | b | null |
| C | a | 2 |
| D | b | 3 |
| E | a | 4 |
| F | a | null |

Any idea how to achieve this?
Thanks, Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `quality` and `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from t
qualify row_number(partition by client
                   order by (case when value is not null then 1 else 2 end),
                            system
                  ) = 1;
```

`Qualify` is a clause that lets you filter on the results of a window function.  The alternative (in other databases) is usually a subquery or CTE.

The key idea is expressing your conditions as an ordering of the rows.  The ordering is:

- Put non-`NULL` values first.
- Order by `system`, so if there are duplicates then `a` comes first.

Comment: Hi Gordon.
thanks for this. Brilliant and I am ashamed :-)

I made a small modification to make it better readible and flexible:
select t.*
from t
qualify row_number(partition by client
                   order by (case when value is not null then 1 else 0 end) DESC,
                            (case when system = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) DESC
                  ) = 1;

Another leason learned thanks to you.
Regards, R.

Comment: @hro1979 - if this answers your question, please accept this as the answer.